# Pseudo Element not visible

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Trying to create a "chat bubble" type of thing and here is my code. The little triangle is made via a pseudo element `::after` but I can't make it show.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```css
 .playernamechat.self-message {
       width: auto;
       background-color: blue;
       border-radius: 12px;
       padding: 5px 10px;
       margin-left: 5px;
       display: inline-block;
       max-width: 280px;
       overflow: hidden;
       float: left;
        position: relative;
        color: white;
      }
  
    .self-message::after {
        content: "";    
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 100%;
        margin-top: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
      }
```

```html
    <span class="playernamechat self-message">hello</span>
```

Comment: The issue is `overflow: hidden;` in the `.playernamechat.self-message` styling. The pseudo element is showing outside it, so this property is hiding it.

Comment: Is there a way to show it while keeping `overflow: hidden`. It is a chat bubble and I do not want it to overflow with text

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there's a way around that. Overflow will hide any content that's outside the constraints of the container.

Comment: You could change the `position: absolute` from `:after` with `position: relative`

Comment: @SWC instead of using `overflow:hidden` I used `overflow-wrap: break-word` which did the same thing but allowed me to have a regular overflow. If you havent already go comment your answer so I can upvote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is showing but hidden. In your CSS remove `overflow: hidden;`. See below:

```css
.playernamechat.self-message {
  width: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 280px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.self-message::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<span class="playernamechat self-message">hello</span>
```